# Wipe / Delete / Clear Simple Response Text to Replace (not Concatenate)

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

In the nodejs actions on google library, calling `.add(text)`, `.ask(text)`, and `.close(text)` on the conversation concatenates that `text` onto the simple text response, i.e.

```typescript
conv.add('hello');
conv.close('world');
// yields text response "hello world"
```

This is normally just fine. But, I'm hitting a case where I need to clear out everything that I've added onto the simple response text to replace it with some error handling response, i.e.

```typescript
conv.add('hello');
// something went wrong, need to clear "hello" and replace
conv.ask('sorry, could you repeat your command?');
// yields text reponse "sorry, could you repeat your command?"
// *does not* yield "hello sorry, could you repeat your command?"
```

I cannot find a function on the conversation object that achieves this behavior. Is there a way I can manually clear out the responses in order to replace them with something new?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I can manually access the `Response[]` array on the conversation object and clear it out with an empty array. So, in the case of my example, I could do:

```typescript
conv.add('hello');
conv.responses = []; // clears out the previously added "hello"
conv.ask('sorry, could you repeat your command?');
// yields text response "sorry, could you repeat your command?"
```